# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' even though I have an instance of the class I'm using

Tags: python, django

When I run my test, which is the following:

```
def test_match_data_while_updating(self):
    match_updated_data = {
        'id': 1,
        'status': 'not_started',
    }    
    match = Match.objects.first()
    
    # TST N.1 : status not_started
    # -------
    match.status = 'not_started'
    request = self.__class__.factory.put('', match_updated_data, format='json')        
    add_authentication_to_request(request, is_staff=True)
    response = update_match_video(request)
    self.assertEqual(Match.objects.first().status,'live')
```

I get the Error that says:

> print('request data get match: ',request.data.get('match').get('id'))
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Here is the function I'm testing:

```
def update_match_video(request):
   print('request data get match: ',request.data.get('match').get('id'))
   if not request.data.get('match').get('id'):
     return JsonResponse({}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

   try:
     match_id = valid_data_or_error(request.data, method='PUT')['match_data']['id']
     match = Match.objects.get(id = match_id)
     db_match_status = match.status

     if db_match_status == 'live':
        valid_data_or_error(request.data, method='PUT')['match_data']['status'] = 'live'
     else:
        if db_match_status == 'closed':
            valid_data_or_error(request.data, method='PUT')['match_data']['status'] = 'closed'
   except Match.DoesNotExist:
      print('Match does  not exist')
```

I will appreciate some help please!

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that `request.data.get('match')`  is returning None?

Comment: yes it is actually returning None and that's the problem I guess, it should not return none since the object match_updated_data is created

Comment: I don't see where you're adding the match object to the request.

Comment: But you never send anything called `match` in the request data.

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley you are right, I've changed the data structure of the object I'm sending and it worked:        match_updated_data = {
            'match': {
                'id': 1,
                'status': 'not_started',
            },

        }

Answer (score 0):

Well, request.data is None:

One way to be certain to hit a function that takes a request argument is to use Django's test client and be certain to PT the value that you are expecting:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.test import TestCase
... other import as needed

class TestMyFunc(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_match_data_while_updating(self):
        match_updated_data = {
        'id': 1,
        'status': 'not_started',
        }    
        match = Match.objects.first()

        # TST N.1 : status not_started
        # -------
        match.status = 'not_started'
        response = self.client.put( .... ) ## JSON of put data -- make certain to PUT "{ .., match: "something!", ..}
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        ... other assertions
```

Now, this creates a test database (and ought to have no side effects (unit test, not integration test)) and can be repeated reliably.

To get django to run this test put it in a directory called tests under the main project directory (adjacent to views, models, etc) and do `python manage.py run tests`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I already have a test database and a tests folder, as Bryan and Daniel commented above, this had to do with the object I was sending, I had to send object match which I didn't

Comment: I tried not to make any assumptions, once I saw the comments I was confident you had a solution.